# Call php from python over telnet

Tags: php, python, telnet

I'm trying to call some php scripts from simple telnet-server written in python. Here it's a code.

```
  # -*- coding: utf8 -*-
  #!/usr/bin/env python
  # скрипт перекидывает выполнение нужного скрипта на определённый порт

  import socket
  import os
  from commands import *
  import subprocess

  #define server properties
  host = ''
  port = 5000
  backlog = 5
  size = 1024

  # configure the server socket
  s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
  s.bind((host,port))
  s.listen(backlog)

  # handle client requests
  while 1:
      client, address = s.accept()
      data = client.recv(size)
      print data
      if data:
  #находим путь для выполняемого скрипта
              recvCommand = data[5:]
              print recvCommand
              userCommand = u'' + recvCommand
              #userCommand = u''+'/home/mechanic/python/forloop.php'
              res = subprocess.call(["php", userCommand])
              client.send(data)

 35     client.close()
```

At the terminal I connect to localhost (telnet localhost 5000) and run command 'calc /home/mechanic/python/forloop.php'. The path is exist in system and I can run him manually. 
But script returned me this error:

```
Could not open input file: /home/mechanic/python/forloop.php
```

But if I write this path manually in python script

```
userCommand = u''+'/home/mechanic/python/forloop.php'
```

All works fine. Where can I take the mistake?

P.S. Here it's a code of forloop.php

```
<?
for (  $i = 0 ;  $i <= 1000000;  $i++  )
echo "Welcome $i times\n";
?>
```

Comment: You should use English in comments I'd say ;)

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried using `recvCommand.strip()` instead of original? I think recvCommand contains newline and carriage return from telnet client.

Your command receiving may sometime fail, there is no guarantee all data will arrive in single recv call. You should concatenate data until you receive newline.
In some cases, your command might arrive in more than one buffers, your code won't be able to work with that.